# Calculating inverse of power series

Tags: power-series, inverse

I found this calculation for the inverse of power series: $$x^2-4x+4.$$

This is the solution:

$$
\frac{1}{x^2-4x+4} = 
$$
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2-x}\right)^2 = 
$$
$$
\frac{1}{4} * \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2 = 
$$
$$
\frac{1}{4} * \left(\sum_{n=0}^\inf \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n \right)^2 =
$$
$$
\frac{1}{4} * \sum_{n=0}^\inf x^n \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n * \left(\frac{1} {2}\right)^{n-k} = 
$$
$$
\frac{1}{4} * \sum_{n=0}^\inf \frac{n+1}{2^n}*x^n.
$$

What I not understand is the last step $\frac{1}{4} * \sum_{n=0}^\inf x^n \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n * \left(\frac{1} {2}\right)^{n-k} = \frac{1}{4} * \sum_{n=0}^\inf \frac{n+1}{2^n}*x^n$.

Why is there $n+1$ in $\frac{1}{2^n}* (n+1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that after $\frac14\left(\frac1{1-x/2}\right)^2$, $x$ vanishes. It should be\begin{align}\frac14\left(\frac1{1-\frac x2}\right)^2&=\frac14\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{2^n}\right)^2\\&=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{2^k}\cdot\frac1{2^{n-k}}\right)x^n\\&=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{2^n}\right)x^n\\&=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{2^n}x^n.\end{align}

Comment: no, my question is, how do I get to (n+1)? I calculated it and i get $\frac{1}{2^n} * x^n$ and not  $\frac{n+1}{2^n} * x^n$

Comment: You are summing $\frac1{2^n}$ $n+1$ times. Therefore, you get $\frac{n+1}{2^n}$. That's how I got the final $=$ in my answer.